# To what extent can I get Aeson to do the heavy lifting?

Tags: haskell, jira, aeson

I'm trying to avoid writing definitions for toJSON. This is the error I encounter:

```
Datatypes.hs:92:10:
    No instance for (aeson-0.6.0.2:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.GToJSON
                       (GHC.Generics.Rep (HashMap Key Project)))
      arising from a use of `aeson-0.6.0.2:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.$gdmtoJSON'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (aeson-0.6.0.2:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.GToJSON
     (GHC.Generics.Rep (HashMap Key Project)))
In the expression:
  (aeson-0.6.0.2:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.$gdmtoJSON)
In an equation for `toJSON':
    toJSON = (aeson-0.6.0.2:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.$gdmtoJSON)
In the instance declaration for `ToJSON (HashMap Key Project)'
```

I get similar errors for all my HashMap `data` declarations.

Here's the relevant code. Let me know if there is missing information.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}  -- for JTask and Fields ToJSON instances:w!
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-} -- This may be needed for HashMaps
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-} -- for the HashMap ToJSON instances
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

import Prelude
import Data.ByteString
import GHC.Generics (Generic )
import Data.Data 
import Data.Typeable (Typeable) -- fix HashMap ToJSON instances? maybe
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Generic  
import Data.Aeson.Types -- (ToJSON,FromJSON)
import Data.HashMap.Strict (HashMap)

data JTask = JTask {fields :: Fields} deriving (Typeable,Data,Generic)
data Fields = Fields { project :: HashMap Key Project
                     , summary :: ByteString
                     , issuetype :: HashMap Name Task
                     , versions :: [HashMap Name Version]
                     , description :: ByteString
                     } deriving (Typeable,Data,Generic)

data Key = Key deriving (Typeable,Data,Generic)
instance Show Key where
   show Key = "key"

data Name = Name deriving (Typeable,Data,Generic)
instance Show Name where
   show Name = "name"

data Task = Task deriving (Typeable,Data,Generic)

type Version = ByteString -- Placeholder type. Probably using Day for realsies.

data Project = BNAP deriving (Typeable,Data,Generic) -- Fill this out as we go 

instance Generic (HashMap Key Project)
instance Data (HashMap Key Project)
--instance GToJSON (HashMap Key Project)

instance Generic (HashMap Name ByteString)
instance Data (HashMap Name ByteString)

instance Generic (HashMap Name Task)
instance Data (HashMap Name Task)
-- JSON instances
instance ToJSON CreateError
instance ToJSON Fields
instance ToJSON JTask 

instance ToJSON Key
instance ToJSON Name
instance ToJSON Task
instance ToJSON Project

instance ToJSON (HashMap Key Project)
instance ToJSON (HashMap Name Task)
instance ToJSON (HashMap Name ByteString)
-- instance ToJSON Version uncomment when we change Version's type.
```

I cannot make an instance for `Data.Aeson.Types.Class.GToJSON` because `Data.Aeson.Types.Class`
is not exported. What are my options? What will I have to write manually? Is `deriveJSON` the best choice?

Update: 
I implemented the suggestion below.
Here's the code

```
createObject :: CreateConf -> ResourceT IO Value
createObject (CreateConf iSummary iDesc dd) = do
   let jfields = Fields {project = singleton Key BNAP
                        ,summary = iSummary
                        ,issuetype = singleton Name Task
                        ,versions = [singleton Name (calcVersion dd)]
                        ,description = iDesc
                        }
return $ toJSON (JTask jfields)
```

The first instance yields `Object fromList [("key",Array (fromList []))])`

Second instance yields `Object fromList [("name",Array (fromList []))]`

any idea why `name` and `key` are empty?

How could I find out?

Would it be easier to just use `deriveJSON`.

update:
Thanks to help from NathanHowell the more important problem has been solved, which is the GToJSON instance for unary types. The solution was to make my own instances for the unary types. The JSON objects are out of order, but I don't know if that matters. If it does, it seems another manual ToJSON instance for Fields would fix that.

update:
Okay a little context. I'm writing a JIRA front-end. I mention that because people in the future may come here to discover the following good news: JIRA doesn't care about Object order.

Comment: `No instance for (aeson-0.6.0.2:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.GToJSON` <- the package version in the message indicates that two versions of `aeson` are involved, and the instance is probably available for the other version of `aeson`. Probably some used library was built against a different aeson version. Make sure only one is used by the `.cabal` file or `-package` flags. Also see if `ghc-pkg check` reports broken packages.

Comment: `GToJSON` isn't exported since they're not intended to be implemented by the end user. This is a common pattern with using `GHC.Generics` to derive typeclass instances.

Comment: This is for a Yesod application. I've imported yesod-json. Is this a matter of choosing between aeson and yesod-json? How else can I make ToJSON instances if I need to use yesod-json instead?

Comment: `yesod-json` seems to use `aeson` for the actual json conversion.

Comment: We do use a patched version of `aeson` here, I don't know if it would change the behavior at all... Try my little test app: https://gist.github.com/964ec113215ff3f49dfb

Comment: I got the exact result you did. `name` and `key` are paired with empty lists.

Comment: Well not exactly, I got this :`{"fields":{"versions":[{"name":"version"}],"project":{"key":[]},"summary":"summary","issuetype":{"name":[]},"description":"description"}}`

Comment: Looks like that is by design for unary constructors: https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/Data/Aeson/Types/Generic.hs#L45

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19508/discussion-between-nathan-howell-and-michael-litchard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aeson provides a `ToJSON` instance for `HashMap String a`. The easiest way to get things working is to use this instance by converting the `HashMap` keys to `Strings`. Just a touch of boilerplate and it uses the `Generic` instances for everything else.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}  -- for JTask and Fields ToJSON instances:w!
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-} -- for the HashMap ToJSON instances
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

import Prelude
import Data.ByteString
import GHC.Generics (Generic )
import Data.Aeson
import Data.HashMap.Strict (HashMap)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap

data JTask = JTask {fields :: Fields} deriving (Generic)
data Fields = Fields { project :: HashMap Key Project
                     , summary :: ByteString
                     , issuetype :: HashMap Name Task
                     , versions :: [HashMap Name Version]
                     , description :: ByteString
                     } deriving (Generic)

data Key = Key deriving (Generic)
instance Show Key where
   show Key = "key"

data Name = Name deriving (Generic)
instance Show Name where
   show Name = "name"

data Task = Task deriving (Generic)

type Version = ByteString -- Placeholder type. Probably using Day for realsies.

data Project = BNAP deriving (Generic) -- Fill this out as we go 

instance ToJSON Fields
instance ToJSON JTask 

instance ToJSON Key
instance ToJSON Name
instance ToJSON Task
instance ToJSON Project

mapfst :: (a -> b) -> [(a, v)] -> [(b, v)]
mapfst f = fmap $ \ (k, v) -> (f k, v)

instance ToJSON a => ToJSON (HashMap Key a) where
  toJSON = toJSON . HashMap.fromList . mapfst show . HashMap.toList

instance ToJSON a => ToJSON (HashMap Name a) where
  toJSON = toJSON . HashMap.fromList . mapfst show . HashMap.toList
```